# Access 2010 crashes with /Runtime flag

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a litte problem with the  `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAboutMicrosoftAccess` command in MS Access 2010 with the */Runtime flag set*.

Access crashes on all machines with Access 2010 Runtime or Access 2010 with the /Runtime flag. Without the /Runtime flag there is no Problem. Access 2002/2003/2007 works also well.. :(

Code that cause the crash:

```
Private Sub BT_Info_Click()
   DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAboutMicrosoftAccess
End Sub
```

The problem seems to be inside the MSO.DLL but I have no idea how to work around. Can anyone help?

Comment: This was discovered and documented recently at Microsoft's forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d8aade76-8f64-46dc-9875-94fd4af86436/access-2010-crashes-with-runcommand-accmdaboutmicrosoftaccess

Comment: Thanks! Since that post at Microsoft is over one year old i am wondering that there is no solution nor a update for the mdo.dll?